# Motion of a satellite orbiting two planets

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity

I came up with this scenario not sure of its plausibility let's say a satellite is orbiting two identical planets in an elliptical shape each planet at the foci

I wanted to determine the motion of the satellite.

I tried this with a string and a pencil, my two fingers being the planets and the pencil being the satellite (The classic ellipse drawing technique)

But since the planets themselves rotate  I had my sister rotate the paper as I drew the ellipse but that didn't end up so well and had numerous rips in the fabric of space and a couple of black holes.

In the end, I would just like to know what would the path taken by this satillite be .

Comment: Simply going "lets say it is an ellipse" is just as arbitrary as "lets say its a triangle", you cannot assume your orbit and just draw it in; you need to use the equations of motion and gravity to derive the orbit. Also, not sure what you mean by 'rip the fabric of space' and what this has to with Black Holes as well.

Comment: @xXx_69_SWAG_69_xXx it was obviously a jest regarding ripping the paper with the pencil. To OP: sorry but you should read a bit about orbital mechanics. if all you had were the 2 planets and your satellite then you can think of a case that might be somewhat stable (each planet orbiting each other and your satellite far away from that system) but not in a solar system. Just take the case of saturn and jupiter. Sometimes you have saturn - sun - jupiter lined up, sometimes sun - jupiter - saturn. Your satellite has no chance to orbit those 2 planets

Comment: Two planets plus a satellite sounds like a three body problem, which does not lend itself to an analytic solution. The best you can do may be a numeric simulation.

Comment: @José Andrade Understood thank you ,I am learning it at the moment but I haven't advanced that far yet .